# IE 7 CSS problem

Tags: html, css

CSS CODE:

```
.search { 
float: left;
width: 100%; 
display: block;
}

.search ul.tabs { 
height: 23px; 
margin: 50px 0 0 0;
padding: 0px; 
} 

/* FF ONLY */
.search ul.tabs, x:-moz-any-link { 
height: 26px; 
margin: 50px 0 0 0;
padding: 0px; 
} 

.search ul.tabs li { 
float: left; 
display: inline; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
} 

.search ul.tabs li.second { 
padding: 0 0 0 2px; 
} 

.search ul.tabs li a { 
padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; 
background: #ffa63c; 
font: normal normal bold 12px/1.5 "Arial", Helvetica, sans; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #fdf9f1;  
font-weight: bold;
}

.search ul.tabs li a:hover { 
color: #fff; 
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div style="float:left">
            <ul class="tabs">
                 <li id="ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_liRestaurnat" class="first">
                <a title="Poišči po imenu" class="activeRestaurant" href="x">Poišči restavracijo</a>
            </li>
            <li id="ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_liAddress" class="second">
                <a title="Poišči po imenu kraja" href="x">Poišči po krajih</a>
            </li>          
            </ul>    
        </div>
```

And i have problem with IE:

FF

[image]

IE 7

[image]

what to do in IE 7?

Comment: What's with `display: inline` and `float: left`? Unless this is a hack that I don't know, floats only apply to boxes.

Comment: problem is that is menu smaller. Look yellow menu.

Comment: try to add line-height along with height: 23px;

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't support rounded corners (they're a feature of CSS3). Consider using the css3pie, jquery ui, or the jquery rounded corner plugin:

http://css3pie.com/

http://jqueryui.com/

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: no is not problem with rounded corners. problem is that is menu smaller. Look yellow menu.

Comment: You probably should have specified what your problem was then. Play around with the padding of `.search ul.tabs li a`. You may have to make it `display: block;` and then float them each left to get the paddings & margins to behave nicely cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the tab height for me in IE7 (actually IE8 in IE7 standards mode):

```
.search ul.tabs li a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

It also works in quirks mode. Apparently the background on an inline element in old IE doesn't expand with the padding.